# Message from application: cannot load such file -- js_regex (LoadError) with client_side_validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, production-environment, client-side-validation

I tried to deploy my Rails app (to Cloud66 and DigitalOcean) but, when accessing the app, it simply says:

> *We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.*

According to the logs (pasted below) the js_regex gem is missing. But I'm having trouble fixing it, because locally everything works as it should. And if I take away the client_side_navigation gem, everything works on production as well. Seems like it cannot load js_regex in production, but I have no idea why. (client_side_validations depends on js_regex)

Using Rails 4.2.2, ruby 2.2.0 and client_side-validations 4.2.1, js_regex is version 1.0.12.

Here are the nginx error logs:

```
— Message from application: cannot load such file --     js_regex (LoadError)
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-  4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations/core_ext/regexp.rb:1:in `require'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations/core_ext/regexp.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations/core_ext.rb:3:in `require'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations/core_ext.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations/active_model.rb:1:in `require'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations/active_model.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations.rb:5:in `require'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/client_side_validations-4f000000a858/lib/client_side_validations.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
— /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
— /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in require'
— /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
— /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
— /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
— /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
— /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/releases/20160127023519/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/releases/20160127023519/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
— /var/deploy/flokky/web_head/releases/20160127023519/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the same, did you find any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I just used:

`gem install js_regex`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made